# Code Igniter simple base url css

Tags: css, codeigniter, url, helper

i want to connect my external css into the page. the css placed on `C:\wamp\www\QBCI\Style\syle.css` and i am using autoload helper `$autoload['helper'] = array("html","form","url");`

so, i write the css connector like this `<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Style/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />` and now here is the view

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>style/style.css" type="text/css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class ="header">
        http://localhost/QBCI/  //i was echoing base_url() 
    </div>

    <div class ="content">


    </div>



</body>
```

and finally, here is my base url at config.php
`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/QBCI';`

[image: stucture]

why is the style.css is not loaded ? what did i do wrong ?

solved, i made the css file "syle.css" instead of "style.css" sorry guys, thank you for your support

Comment: Can we have a link to a demo, or maybe the content of your htaccess if you have one? Or maybe the value returned by `base_url()`?

Comment: @nebulousgirl i did <?php echo base_url() ?> at the view's div, it prints like this `http://localhost/QBCI/ `

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('style/style.css'); ?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Make sure your `.htaccess` works and your `style/` directory is in the right place (in the same folder with **index.php** in most cases).

As you are using a subfolder (*QBCI*), make sure you have it in your `.htaccess` rewrite path.

Comment: why don't you prefer to use base_url() ?

Comment: `base_url();` should be used in this case as `site_url();` is for page urls. See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: I am really sorry, I have mistaken here, surely base_url() should be used. Editing my answer

Comment: @nebulousgirl  sorry, still not work, i made this <link href="<?php echo base_url('style/style.css'); ?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: @nencor what does firebug/developer tools show you? What error do you get? What do you see in `view source`?

Comment: @vlakarados thread edited, i'm using netbean PHP , and mozilla firefox

Comment: Well, that shows you that the function works just fine, have you set up your `.htaccess` file right by ignoring `style/` folder?

Comment: @vlakarados how do i do that ? i wasn't edited my `.htaccess` since the beginning

Comment: Include the it in your question, please

Comment: @nencor tell us your solution then!

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to set `$config['base_url'] = '';` in your `config/config.php`?

Additionally the documentation suggests that you pass the `base_url` function the path instead of concatenating it, it shouldn't make that big of difference but..
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a trailing slash to your `base_url` value:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/QBCI/';
```

Comment: If you view source in your web browser, what value is the `href` value corresponding to your style sheet?

Comment: Ok, @nencor, if you click on that link in the source viewer of your web browser, does it display the CSS?

Comment: no it isn't, it display <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /QBCI/style/style.css was not found on this server.</p>
    </body></html>

Comment: @nencor personally I'd make the path lower case (try changing the folder from 'Style' to 'style') and all of the references to it lower case too.

Answer (score 0):

your file is under Style/syle.css not style.css you must rename the file because you are missing a t